# Prove $\nexists$ $a,b$ $\in$ $ \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ s.t. $ae^{t}+ae^{-t}=-be^t+be^{-t}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $\nexists$ $a,b$ $\in$  $ \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ s.t. $ae^{t}+ae^{-t}=-be^t+be^{-t}$.

I was trying to show linear independence.

Comment: Zero relation with number theory. In fact is a question of linear algebra.

Comment: Linear independence can be a good road, thus not the only one, nor the simplest. Can you please post also your efforts in this direction, highlighting where you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a+b\neq 0,$ the given equation is equivalent to $e^{2t}=\dfrac{b-a}{b+a}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can you prove the linear independence of $e^t$, $e^{-t}$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exist $a,b \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with $ae^t + ae^{-t} = -be^t+be^{-t}$.

Equating coefficients of $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$ respectively, we get $a=-b$ and $a=b$, or $a=-a$.

This implies both $a$ and $b$ must be $0$, hence the contradiction.